# How to compose the query in the right way?

Tags: sql, t-sql, bcp

I have the following query that I think is composed the wrong way.
When building the `@query` variable, I'm not sure how to include single/double quotation marks

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @bcpCommand VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @sharedDevFolder VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @environment VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @customerCode VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @parserConfig VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @bucketAssign VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @dateFormat VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @RC INT

SET @sharedDevFolder = '\\REMOTESERVER\DataFeed\'
SET @fileName = 'Transaction-' + 
                    @environment + '-' + 
                    @customerCode + '-' + 
                    @parserConfig + '-' + 
                    @bucketAssign + '-' + 
                    @dateFormat + '.txt'
SET @query = 
   'SELECT "Transaction Unique ID", "Transaction Date", "Person Unique ID"
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        NULL AS "Transaction Unique ID", CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS "Transaction Date",
        NULL AS "Person Unique ID"
    FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE YYYYMM = 201507'

    SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "' + @query + '" queryout "'
    SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @sharedDevFolder + @fileName + '" -c  -T -t^| -r\n'

    EXEC @RC = master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

I have an output: `NULL` executing it.
I'm not sure how to compose the query the right way

Comment: instead of using a `-T` option in the `@bcpcommand`, try using `-S servername -U username -P password` for the database

Answer (score 1):

If any of the concatenated variable is NULL then @query will be NULL.

To scape quotation use two singles quotes:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(100)
SET @query = 'select ''string'''
PRINT @query
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but if you have single quotes that are part of the data, they have to be escaped by a single quote, e.g.:

```
select 'Today''s the day of the company''s big announcement'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the double Quotation markings with 2 single quotes.

Ex.

```
SET @query = 
   'SELECT ''Transaction Unique ID'', ''Transaction Date'', ''Person Unique ID''
        UNION ALL
```

Comment: how do I write complete statement. It seems that something obviously not right